# can't load a usb key formatted on a windows machine

Tags: 12.04, usb

I'm trying to read files off a usb that was formatted as Fat32 on a windows machine. 
When I plug it into my usb drive, it says : "Could not mount the following disk: USB DISK". 
And then in the Dolphin file explorer, i see the following message at the bottom of the screen:  "An error occurred while accessing 'USB DISK', the system responded: An unspecified error has occurred.: Daemon is inhibited".

I'm not sure why this is the case. 
I noticed that in gparted, there is an option to format a drive as Fat32... so ubuntu should be able to read Fat32 drives, I assume

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.